# Spring MVC: No handler found for correctly resolved JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat, spring-mvc

I have written a simple Spring MVC application which has a Controller method mapped to a URL:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/person_list")
public ModelAndView getPersonList()
{
    // get the list of all persons from the database and set this as the only member of our model map
    List<Person> personList = personDao.list();
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("person_list", personList);

    // pass it on as a model and view, view should resolve to "list_persons.jsp"
    return new ModelAndView("list_persons", "model", model);
}
```

When the URL is requested via a browser I get a 404 page, and in the Tomcat log I see a message telling me that the correctly resolved JSP view file, /WEB-INF/jsp/list_persons.jsp, is not found:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/my_app/WEB-INF/jsp/list_persons.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

In my Spring application context configuration I have used a pretty standard view resolver set up:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" /> 
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
</bean>
```

If I go into the Tomcat webapps directory where the application is deployed I can see the JSP file is where it's supposed to be, `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/my_app/WEB-INF/jsp/list_persons.jsp`.

Maybe the file is being found but there is another handler mapping step that supposed to happen that I've skipped?  My assumption is that once this JSP page is referenced as the view in the response then the JSP should render as HTML in the browser.  I can get expected results from other views which are classes extending AbstractView, but plain JSPs give no joy.

Why isn't this working as expected?

Comment: Show us your web.xml.

Comment: dispatcher config might help here

Comment: please post us your dispatcher servlet

Comment: @ Hitham It is possible to access the `jsp` inside the web-inf . i dont understand the upvote here

Comment: It was indeed the dispatcher configuration in the web.xml which was causing my woes, please see my update.  Thanks for the helpful comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me like you have a `url-pattern` of `/*` for your `DispatcherServlet`. You have to know that a typical servlet container will have a `Servlet` implementation for handling JSPs. This `JspServlet` is typically mapped with extension mapping, like `*.jsp`. [The path mapping pattern `/*` is matched before extension mapping.](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) Therefore, your `DispatcherServlet` will be chosen to handle the internal forward to

```
/my_app/WEB-INF/jsp/list_persons.jsp
```

but it won't have an appropriate handler.

By changing the `DispatcherServlet` mapping to `/`, it becomes the default servlet which is matched last, so the Servlet container will have already chosen the `JspServlet` to handle the `RequestDispatcher` `forward`.

Comment: I actually figured this out on my own but you have made a good explanation as to why it works out like this.  Nice job, and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This forward all requests to spring dispatcher

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Yes as you said the `url-pattern` will send the request with patterns here to the spring dispatcher servlet. if specify something like `.htm` , only those requests will be handled by dispatcher as the `web.xml` loads first

Comment: This is correct, Sotirios above got the answer right as well and a minute before with another nice explanation, sorry I can't mark both as the correct answer.  Thanks for your help, I wish I had asked for help here sooner than I did!

Answer (score -2):

*(Posting the answer on behalf of the question author in order to move it to the answer space)*.

This was resolved by changing the servlet mapping in the web.xml from /* to /, i.e from this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

to this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```